# How to make video play on web by using url, but can not access by direct link?

Tags: php, video, media-player, media, jwplayer

How to make video play on web by using url, but can not access by direct link ?

**Now I use jw player**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("mediaplayer1889082201").setup({
                            flashplayer: "jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                            file: "http://testhost.com/myproject/files/1/video/coursecreeklruprr4nags7ee1codeschool_756.mp4",
                            image: "http://testhost.com/myproject/files/1/video/coursecreeklruprr4nags7ee1codeschool_756.jpg",
                            width: "800",
                            height: "510",
                            stretching: "uniform",
                            skin: "jwplayer/jwplayer-skins-free/six.xml",
                            abouttext: "myproject",
                            aboutlink: "myproject",
                    });
            </script>
```

So I can using http://testhost.com/myproject/files/1/ to access to folder (Look this link by inspect element)

I want video play on jw player.But i don't want user on web access by direct url to folder that contain video.

Thaks you.

Comment: Wow, I understand maybe 30% of your post.. Which is the code you posted....... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I want video play on jw player.But i don't want user on web access by direct url to foder that contain video.

Comment: Then, serve your video trough a file which verify the page is requesting it and not a user.

Comment: How to, Can you gulide?

Comment: I tested by use .htaccess after that jw player can not acess to video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand you want to serve the video file to the script, but you don't want users being able to navigate to the video url and download/view it from there.

### A quick example using PHP

Change your code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer("mediaplayer1889082201").setup({
                            flashplayer: "jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                            file: "video.php?file=coursecreeklruprr4nags7ee1codeschool_756.mp4",
                            image: "http://testhost.com/myproject/files/1/video/coursecreeklruprr4nags7ee1codeschool_756.jpg",
                            width: "800",
                            height: "510",
                            stretching: "uniform",
                            skin: "jwplayer/jwplayer-skins-free/six.xml",
                            abouttext: "myproject",
                            aboutlink: "myproject",
                    });
            </script>
```

As you can see, we are sending a file request to `video.php`, then we'll create that file serving the video only when the referrer is your webpage which will be able to show it.

Go ahead and create `video.php` in the same folder.

First we need to check if a file has been given in the url, like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['file']) {
}
```

Then we check if the referrer is your page, like this:

```
if (strpos($ref,'testhost.com/myproject/files/1') !== 0){
}
```

If it's your page we can start serving your file, like this:

```
$path = 'video/' . $_GET['file'];
header("X-Sendfile: $path");
```

So the whole thing together:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['file']) {
    if (strpos($ref,'testhost.com/myproject/files/1') !== 0){
        $path = 'video/' . $_GET['file'];
        header("X-Sendfile: $path");
    }
}
```

Look out; this is a very quick EXAMPLE, not a safe-and-ready-to-use-script! Their has to be security checks build in, and you're serving a file even when it's not existing, so that kind of checks still has to be made to make it ready for use.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider accepting the answer by clicking the 'check' icon on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under:

```
stretching: "uniform",
```

Add:

```
type: "mp4",
```

This way, the JW Player can read the file if it does not have a file extension.